# Getting redundant packages added into the Nuget Feed

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, package, nuget

I will describe my steps to see where I hit the problem.

1. I Created new class library (.NET Standard), wrote required solution, packed it.
2. Pushed this package to Azure DevOps.
3. Created new asp.net Core Web Application project.
4. Selected my custom Package Source as the only enabled source.
5. Installed package from this solution.
6. After some period of time other packages were added to this Nuget Feed. For example, bootrstrap, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc etc.

If there is anyone who could give a hint, solution or guide in which direction should I keep on looking for a source of the problem, that would be very helpful.

Comment: what's the actual probelm? What's the error message?

Comment: I don`t have any error. It`s rather me not understanding why after some period of time I get additional packages appeared in the Nuget feed. Even though I have not pushed these packages to the feed...

Comment: ok, in that case Daniel Mann's answer is correct. When you projects use packages like bootstrap, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc and others and it requests the package from the Azure Artifacts feed, if upstreaming is enabled, Azure Artifacts will download them from nuget.org and put it in the feed for you. You should turn off upstreaming or upsourcing, whatever it's called, if you don't want that.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks are deserved to Daniel Mann for understanding your question when I did not and giving the correct answer. You can do so by accepting his answer as the accepted answer and upvoting it if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I expect the package source for all of those packages is "NuGet".

You have upstream sources enabled. This is expected behavior; your feed is synchronizing all of the application's required packages from NuGet.org, so that you only need to restore from a single feed, your Artifacts feed.